# Beautiful soup how print a tag while iterating over it

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

My xml looks like this, I want to get the locations.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<playlist version="1" xmlns="http://xspf.org/ns/0/">
 <trackList>
  <track>
   <location>file:///home/ashu/Music/Collections/randomPicks/ipod%20on%20sep%2009/Coldplay-Sparks.mp3</location>
   <title>Coldplay-Sparks</title>
  </track>
  <track>
   <location>file:///home/ashu/Music/Collections/randomPicks/gud%201s/Coldplay%20Warning%20sign.mp3</location>
   <title>Coldplay Warning sign</title>
  </track>....
```

I am trying:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs
soup = bs (the_above_xml_text)
for track in soup.tracklist:
    print track.location.string
```

But that is not working because I am getting:

```
AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'location'
```

How can I achieve the result, thanks in advance.

Comment: yes i ommited that part for the sake of Brevity you want me to show it all ?

Comment: Yes. Also explain what "not working" means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `findAll` :

```
>>> for track in soup.findAll('track'):
...     print track.title.string
...     print track.location.string
... 
Coldplay-Sparks
file:///home/ashu/Music/Collections/randomPicks/ipod%20on%20sep%2009/Coldplay-Sparks.mp3
Coldplay Warning sign
file:///home/ashu/Music/Collections/randomPicks/gud%201s/Coldplay%20Warning%20sign.mp3
```

Comment: does findAll uses some kind of pattern matching ? using findAll seems to undermine the whole point of having a structured document

Answer (score 1):

Use [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/), it's faster and supports xpath:

```
>>> doc = lxml.etree.fromstring(yourxml)
>>> doc.xpath('//n:location/text()', namespaces={'n': 'http://xspf.org/ns/0/'})
['file:///home/ashu/Music/Collections/randomPicks/ipod%20on%20sep%2009/Coldplay-Sparks.mp3',
'file:///home/ashu/Music/Collections/randomPicks/gud%201s/Coldplay%20Warning%20sign.mp3']
```

Comment: @Bunny: Learning XPath good enough to cover 80% of all problems is a matter of 30 minutes.

Comment: nosklo  ,  thanks for the advice , i'll defenetly learn that , but probably the next weekend :P